# Disable Specific Cipher Suites Apache with WHM/cPanel

Tags: ssl, openssl

We are operating a few web servers that have WHM/cPanel installed so we can easily mange our sites and projects. To ensure our information and users information is secured, we have been running some security tests. All our servers currently supporting anonymous cypher suites; specifically:

```
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc016)
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc018)
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA (0xc017)
                 and
TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc019)
```

What is the best way to disable these without messing up our websites?

Answer (score 7):

To add those directives to Apache via WHM you'd add them via :

Apache Configuration > Include Editor > Pre Main Include

and of course with the new issue with Poodle and disabling SSL v3 you'd probably want to make it :

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

However I believe you may also need to update the SSL Cipher suite settings within

Apache Configuration > Global Configuration > SSL Cipher Suite

to something like this :

```
ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-EXP:!kEDH:!aNULL
```

Certainly when I updated my servers to disable SSLv3 and also disable the ciphers that allow anonymous authentication, doing the first bit alone still showed my server as reported them as being available, but doing the second part as well fixed it.

Comment: I can confirm that these steps mitigate POODLE on CentOS 6.5 running WHM / cPanel according to the Qualys SSL Labs SSL Server Test.

Comment: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0xc011)   WEAK 128 ; TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA (0x5)   WEAK 128 ; 
TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 (0x4)   WEAK 128 ; any ideas for theses one please?

Answer (score 1):

When I looked at WHM > Service Configuration > Apache Configuration > Global Configuration > SSL Cipher Suite, I found that the entry allowed older SSL protocols. Simply selecting the **default** radio button and rebuilding the config file and restarting Apache server seemed sufficient to force the use of just four secure protocols, eliminating the protocols that had been displayed in orange.

I judged this by running the security tool https://sslanalyzer.comodoca.com/ on my website.

I wish the security specifications were simpler and less error-prone to specify in WHM.

With WHM, I like to select the **default** choices unless I have a good reason to specify something different.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to edit your Apache configuration file and change some SSL directives.

Usually you can do it by change in `SSLCipherSuite` directive. The topic was discussed few times on StackExchange, i.e. here: [“Optimal” Web Server SSL Cipher Suite Configuration](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/51680/optimal-web-server-ssl-cipher-suite-configuration/51730#51730).

Please see also [SSL configuration for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) for more details.

I hope it will help somehow.

**EDIT:**

Exemplary hardened configuration can look like that:

```
SSLProtocol ALL -SSLv2
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

However, please remember to adjust it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to disable **SSL2** and **SSL3** and enable **TLS**

For WHM=> Apache Configuration => Include Editor => Pre Main Include

And Select ALL version

```
SSLHonorCipherOrder On
SSLProtocol -All +TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2 -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

after all **restart Apache**

And if still Not supporting properly then I suggest you rebuild apache by **Easyapache**